# Windows 7 returns "command not found" when giving the more command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, more

On my machine I can call the `more` command, but my colleague cannot. We both open the command-line as Administrator, but that doesn't help. What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you have cywgin or similar software installed?

Comment: What's the output if your colleague runs `where more`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "cmdextensions" settings on each machine

However beware, one of you, or your admins, must have had a reason for changing it